# mod_fcgi + APC + Shared Memory

Tags: apache, memcached, apc

One of my sites is growing and I'm having scalability issues. My knowledge with this new software is rather small, my hosting company doesn't have a clue either.

Shared Memory is not working since variables are not cached between requests, is there a way to make this work? At the moment the script is relying on Memcached but there is the TCP/IP overhead.

Will PHP-FPM automatically solve this problem ? Since it comes bundled with PHP 5.3.3 maybe an upgrade of PHP will suffice ?

== OUTPUT FROM apc.php ==

General Cache Information

APC: 3.0.19
PHP: 5.2.14
Server: Apache/2.2.16 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.16 OpenSSL/0.9.8e-fips-rhel5 mod_bwlimited/1.4 mod_fcgid/2.3.5
Shared Memory: 1 Segment(s) with 128.0 MBytes
(mmap memory, pthread mutex locking)

File Cache Information
Cached Files 91 ( 4.2 MBytes)
Hits 245
Misses 92
Request Rate (hits, misses) 0.41 cache requests/second
Hit Rate 0.30 cache requests/second
Miss Rate 0.11 cache requests/second
Insert Rate 0.11 cache requests/second
Cache full count 0

User Cache Information (PROBLEM!!!!)

Cached Variables 0 ( 0.0 Bytes)
Hits 0
Misses 0
Request Rate (hits, misses) 0.00 cache requests/second
Hit Rate 0.00 cache requests/second
Miss Rate 0.00 cache requests/second
Insert Rate 0.00 cache requests/second
Cache full count 0

Runtime Settings

apc.cache_by_default 1
apc.coredump_unmap 0
apc.enable_cli 0
apc.enabled 1
apc.file_update_protection 2
apc.filters 
apc.gc_ttl 3600
apc.include_once_override 0
apc.max_file_size 10M
apc.mmap_file_mask /tmp/apc.RqsiCE
apc.num_files_hint 1024
apc.report_autofilter 0
apc.rfc1867 0
apc.rfc1867_freq 0
apc.rfc1867_name APC_UPLOAD_PROGRESS
apc.rfc1867_prefix upload_
apc.shm_segments 1
apc.shm_size 128
apc.slam_defense 0
apc.stat 1
apc.stat_ctime 0
apc.ttl 7200
apc.user_entries_hint 4096
apc.user_ttl 7200
apc.write_lock 1

Answer (score 0):

What are you using in your PHP code to try storing and fetching variables? Are you sure you're using APC to store variables? Try to create a sample code to check out if you're using everything properly.

Try to enable apc.enable_cli
I've worked with APC with fastCGI - php-cgi and php-fpm